# How Do I Take Still Images?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i want to add a camerapreviewlayer and a take photo action but i dont know how.
Can someone help me.
Im new in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

If it's an `CALayer` (which I'm pretty sure it is, but I'll verify it now), you can do this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext();
[yourCameraPreviewLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGrahpicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**Edit:** I presume you're using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, then it is a `CALayer`, so above should work.

Comment: You know i want the previewlayer in little square like the app hipstamtic it should not be all over the display and i want to add effects when i know how to add the camera

Comment: You can easily perform those operations with an `UIImage` (the class `image` is). There're some categories out there to help you achieve this =).

Comment: what frameworks do i need and do i have to put this code in in myviewcontroller.m ?
Sorry im new in xcode

Comment: You do not need any additional frameworks (you already got AVFoundation). You can put it in the method-body you want to take stills from.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of taking a photo: https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake